# Model ImageField and save in a specific path

Tags: django, django-models

This is my model:

```
def group_based_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return "media/image/lavorazione/{}".format(instance.prestazione.id,)

class ImmaginiLavorazioni(models.Model):
    immagine = models.ImageField(upload_to=group_based_upload_to)
    prestazione = models.ForeignKey(Listino, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
                                    blank=True, default=None, related_name='Listino3')
```

and my form:

```
class ImmagineUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = ImmaginiLavorazioni
    exclude = ('preventivo', )
```

I need a view to save an image in a specific path.
The name of path must be the pk of foreign key.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I use a model of how a blog post works. You can adjust the example on your needs. You should try and avoid saving the location path from a view.

On your models.py:

```py
# Create your models here.
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    filebase, extension = filename.split(".")
    return "%s/%s" % (instance.id, filename)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug  = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            height_field="height_field",
            width_field="width_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = HTMLField()
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': AdminPagedownWidget },
    }
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

On your forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from pagedown.widgets import PagedownWidget
from pagedown.widgets import AdminPagedownWidget
from .models import Post


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=False))
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
            "image"
        ]

class PostModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=AdminPagedownWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

And on your settings.py:

```py
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
```

Here is your view.py:

```py
# Create your views here.
def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Succefully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The next code has an example without form but you can modify based on your needs.

Below the `settings.py`

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../media')
```

Firstable, I defined the path of the image in the `helpers.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime

def upload_to_image_post(self, filename):
    """
    Stores the image in a specific path regards to date 
    and changes the name of the image with for the name of the post
    """    
    current_date = datetime.now()

    return '%s/posts/main/{year}/{month}/{day}/%s'.format(
        year=current_date.strftime('%Y'), month=current_date.strftime('%m'), 
        day=current_date.strftime('%d')) % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)
```

You could define the image's name with some code like this one. But you have to regard you should have the pk to replace the name of the image

```
ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
name = self.pk
filename = '%s.%s' % (name, ext)
```

So, I called the def in my `models.py`, specifically in the image's field

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from .helpers import upload_to_image_post

class Post(models.Model):
    """
    Store a simple Post entry. 
    """
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200, help_text='Title of the post')
    body = models.TextField('Body', help_text='Enter the description of the post')   
    slug = models.SlugField('Slug', max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True, help_text='Title in format of URL')        
    image_post = models.ImageField('Image', max_length=80, blank=True, upload_to=upload_to_image_post, help_text='Main image of the post')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
```

I hope this helped you

Answer (score 0):

Now this is my models:

def group_based_upload_to(instance, immagine):
    return "media/preventivo/{pk}/{image}".format(pk=instance.preventivo.id, image=immagine)

class ImmaginiLavorazioni(models.Model):
    immagine = models.ImageField(upload_to=group_based_upload_to)
    preventivo = models.ForeignKey(Preventivo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                               default=None, related_name='Listino3')

And this is my view:

def upload_immagine(request, pk):

```
member = get_object_or_404(Preventivo, pk=pk)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImmagineUploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        newimmagine = form.save(commit=False)
        newimmagine.preventivo_id = member.pk
        newimmagine.save()

        return redirect('preventivo_new2', pk=member.pk)

else:
    form = ImmagineUploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
return render(request, 'FBIsystem/upload_immagine.html', {'member': member, 'form': form})
```

It save in db the file path and the foreign key like:

immagine= media/preventivo/6/image.jpg
preventivo_id = 6

but not create a folder and not save the uploaded image...